# Why is my multiprocessing-enabled script creating only 4 out of 10 folders?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to modify my script to copy files across using multiprocessing as an exercise for me learn more about multiprocessing in python

my main does this

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #get command line arguments
    cmdlineArgs = getCmdLineArguments()
    #get all the files in folder
    listOfFiles = getFiles(cmdlineArgs.sourceDirectory)
    #create dataframe of files which needs to be copied
    filesDF = createDF(listOfFiles, cmdlineArgs.destDirectory)
    processes = []
    lstOfDates = list(set(filesDF['date'].to_list()))
    lstOfDates.sort()
    # for dt in lstOfDates:
    #     copyFilesAcross([filesDF, [dt]])
    splitListOfDatesForProc = [(lstOfDates[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(lstOfDates), 3)]
    for dt in splitListOfDatesForProc:
        p = Process(target=copyFilesAcross, args=([filesDF, dt],))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

copyFilesAcross does this :

```
def copyFilesAcross(lst):
    #keep only the date provided as parameter
    df = lst[0]
    dt = lst[1]
    for d in dt:
        df = df[df.date == d]
        print("Processing date " + d + ' for PID: ', os.getpid())
        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            try:
                #print('Making directory ' + row['destination'])
                os.makedirs(row['destination'], exist_ok=True)
                shutil.copy(row['source'], row['destination'])
            except OSError as e:
                print('Failed to copy file ' + row['source'] + ' with error {0}'.format(e) )
            except:
                print("Unexpected error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

output :

```
getFiles: Executed ...
getFiles: Creating empty list ...
getFiles: Concatenating files ...
Creating dataframe of files to be copied ...
Creating empty dataframe ...
Populating dataframe ...
Sorting data frame by date ...
Processing date 20180204 for PID:  35033 <- processed
Processing date 20180304 for PID:  35034 <- processed
Processing date 20180811 for PID:  35038 <- processed
Processing date 20180815 for PID:  35041 <- processed
Processing date 20180311 for PID:  35034 <- not processed
Processing date 20180724 for PID:  35034 <- not processed
Processing date 20180222 for PID:  35033 <- not processed
Processing date 20180303 for PID:  35033 <- not processed
Processing date 20180812 for PID:  35038 <- not processed
Processing date 20180813 for PID:  35038 <- not processed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Without multiprocessing the script runs fine so I assume the issue is in the last 2 for loops in main, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a multiprocessing problem, you just have a bug in your code.

On the first loop iteration in `copyFilesAcross`, you overwrite `df`, and throw away every line other than the one that matches the first date in `dt`. On the next (and all subsequent) iteration of `for d in dt:`, you try to find a different date which won't exist, and you then overwrite `df` with an empty dataframe. When you call `for index,row in df.iterrows():`, there are no rows, so the loop never executes at all.